# How to add multiple tags before a single tag BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a single tag

I need to add three a tags before it having different text, I tried as:

```
headTag = soup.find_all('h1', text='Attendance List')
aTag = soup.new_tag('a') 
aTag['class'] = "btn btn-default pull-right"
aTag.string = "Today"
headTag[0].insert_before(aTag)
aTag.string = "Weekly"
headTag[0].insert_before(aTag)
aTag.string = "Monthly"
headTag[0].insert_before(aTag)
```

But its only adding the last one, is there a better approach to do this without declaring multiple variables?

Comment: Could you give a minimal example and what you expect? It seems you insert same tag `aTag`, you can try `aTag1 = soup.new_tag('a')` and insert it

Comment: I was trying to avoid multiple declarations, the given answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are only creating one tag, and then repeatedly modifying its `string` attribute, instead of creating three separate tags and inserting all of them. This is why it is only appending a single tag, and why the end result is the last of the strings.

To do what you want, use a for loop and create a new tag for each of the strings, like this:

```
headTag = soup.find_all('h1', text='Attendance List')

for s in ["Today", "Weekly", "Monthly"]:
    aTag = soup.new_tag('a') 
    aTag['class'] = "btn btn-default pull-right"
    aTag.string = s
    headTag[0].insert_before(aTag)
```

Comment: Do you have to be working with an entire document for this? I have tried running with shell html structure and nothing is inserted. https://pastebin.com/9PhksqW3

Comment: @QHarr - It is being inserted, you're just not seeing it because you are doing `print(html)` at the end of your code, instead of `print(soup)`. The original html string isn't modified. Only the bs4 object.